# Run New Relic in Xamarin Android application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, newrelic

I am trying to figure out how to run NewRelic mobile on xamarin forms android application. I found [this repository](https://github.com/nberardi/newrelic-mobile-xamarin). It is pretty old, but i tried o put latest .jar file and native library builds just fine. After i connect compiled dll to client project, i cant find a way to initialize newrelic, b/c there is no NewRelicHelper class, though it was declared in binidng metadata. Can you help and tell me how to find class that i need and initialize newrelic? [Here](https://github.com/F0rc0sigan/xamarin.android.newrelic) is repo where you can reproduce issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it at least a step further, but it is still not working 100%
If you right click the csproj in visual studio and go to properties, in the Application Tab change the Android Class Parser to "class-parse" and the NewRelicHelper will now be in the dll, but the withApplicationToken method is not there.